# Page Showing Only "ion_auth"

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Trying to run my site locally and all that I see in the browser is "ion_auth" no errors or anything.  Nothing else is loading. The code ends up looking like this in the inspector

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
       <body>
              ion_auth
        </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone run into this problem?

Comment: how could we possibly know what the issue is if all you do is give us the final output? how about some details on your setup?

Answer (score 0):

change your ion library... and if it is not working ... thn try to load your page without ion library... comment ion library code from every where and remove ion from auto load and debug it..